# IE8 gets caught in an infinite loop with array push

Tags: javascript

I am confused the following loop causing an infinite loop in IE8

```
for (var i in theArray) {
            this.theArray.push(theArray[i]);
}
```

IE8 get caught in an infinite loop which I don't understand why because `this.theArray` is a global array while `theArray` is a local variable.

If I had something like the following I would understand that an infinite loop would occurs:

```
for (var i in theArray) {
            theArray.push(theArray[i]);
}
```

This only happens in IE8. Does IE8 treat variables and scoping differently?

EDIT

Here is what I have within an object

```
this.theArray = new Array();

this.selection = function(theArray) {
    for (var i in theArray) {
        this.theArray.push(theArray[i]);
    }
}
```

EDIT

I found out that I am pass the global variable into the function as an argument. Duh! Why does this not work in IE8?

Comment: Where does this code run? In the global scope?

Comment: Why not change the name of the local var?????

Comment: can we see the whole code? or at least a stripped down version that we can test on. also, what does the console of the other browsers say? other browsers have an internal "breaker" when a loop goes infinite.

Comment: I've added the code I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, never use `for in` loop on an array. It will iterate through the values as well as augmented properties.

Then, `this` cannot be determined in your code. `this` might refer to the global object. Also, you might have missed using `var` in the local variable, thus making `theArray` point to the same global `theArray` you are appending to.

```
var theArray = [1,2,3];

function foo(){
    theArray = [4,5,6]; //missing var, theArray is the global theArray
    for (var i in theArray) {
        //you are pushing to the same array you are fetching from
        this.theArray.push(theArray[i]);

        //[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,.....]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `self` instead of `this`

`self` is the window or frame the script runs in, so it's like accessing the global variable.

```
for (var i in theArray) {
    self.theArray.push(theArray[i]);
}
```

If that doesn't help, give the Arrays different variable names.

Or: Are you sure that `theArray` is of local scope? Did you prefix the `var` statement before defining `theArray?

```
var theArray
```

Comment: window.theArray is even more understandable

Comment: @RobW I deleted my comment after some research

Answer (score 0):

The way I read this, it should go into an infinite loop. You are enumerating over an array and adding items to it at the same time, ie:

Read index i, create i+1, repeat.

Other languages bomb out when you are modifying a collection you are enumerating over, which would have given you an indication of the error.

I'm surprised it only fails in IE8. Am I misreading your code snippet?